# Unable to get the exact tag value of a UIView

Tags: iphone, ipad, tags, nsnumber

I am trying to compare a view tag with another tag by using the following code

```
for(UIView *subView in cardsContainerView.subviews){

    NSNumber *viewTag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:subView.tag];
    NSLog(@"The subView tag is %d",viewTag);
    if([[dataDict valueForKey:@"savedPositions"]containsObject:viewTag]){
        [tempArray addObject:viewTag];
        [self rearrangeView:subView and:subView];
    }
```

But after seeing the Log statements i found out that my tag value is no where close to what i have given it previously.  Theh tag that i got is this

> 89212864.

can anyone help me know the reason for this behavior please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewTag is an object, if you just pass that to the NSLog it will print you the id of the instance (in the context of an integer), which is what gives you the weird result. You have to ask viewTag for its integer Value:

```
NSLog(@"The subView tag is %d", [viewTag intValue]);
```

Comment: oooh..... How did i miss this one.... Thanku so much robin.. i will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

```
for(UIView *subView in cardsContainerView.subviews){

    NSNumber *viewTag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:subView.tag];
    NSLog(@"The subView tag is %d",[viewTag intValue]);
    if([[dataDict valueForKey:@"savedPositions"]containsObject:viewTag]){
        [tempArray addObject:viewTag];
        [self rearrangeView:subView and:subView];
    }
```

Try this

Comment: I beat robin by 15 seconds to the answer but you accepted his answer. No problem, care to vote up?

Comment: Hey, sorry dude... i'v decided to give you a vote up, but somehow i forgot it.... Thanks for reminding it man... Now u can check ur votes count.... Cheers.....